# How to apply Bayes' theorem on a contingency in which the sampled distribution differs drastically from the entire population?

Tags: bayesian, contingency-tables, sensitivity-specificity

**Summary**: How can I calculate my probability of being truly positive based on a contingency table that has a completely different distribution than the total population?

I was recently confronted with a simple 2 by 2 contingency table that shows the results of a medical trial where `D` represents the true condition of a patient and `T` the test result. As can be seen, the prevalence of the condition in the sample is 10% and I can easily compute my probability of being truly positive given a positive test result.

$$P(D+|T+) = \frac{P(T+|D+)P(D+)}{P(T+)} =  \frac{0.9 \times 0.1}{0.18} = 0.5$$

Now comes the information into play that the general prevalence of the condition in the population is 1% instead of **10%**.
$P(D+) = 0.01$

$P(T+)$ of the general population should obviously change but how would $P(T+|D+)$ be impacted?

|  | D+ | D- | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T+ | 9 | 9 | 18 |
| T- | 1 | 81 | 8 |
| Total | 10 | 90 | 100 |

Is it possible to somehow *update* the contingency table in a way that it represents the the general population more accurately but still shows the correct sensitivity and specificity of the test? Can I use this table to infer about the probability of having the condition for someone outside the trial sample?

Comment: You could always weight your data - as in, "I undersampled D- by a factor of 11, so I will weight my D- column by 11x".   (11 gets you to D+/(D+ + D-) = 0.01.)  Then run the same calculations as above with the modified numbers.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @jbowman ! I thought about something similar but it seemed to trivial but if that's the way to go, I will go for it.